# SLide Div in from left and div our from right on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get this effect on a navigation div... http://www.vogue.co.uk/topic/vogue-view (click the menu and filters icons) I have this

```
var boxes = $('ul.topLevelNavigation');

$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if (!box.hasClass("current")) {
        var current = $('.current');
        current.stop().animate({left: '150%',}, 500 ).removeClass('current');
        box.stop().animate({left: '50%',}, 500 ).addClass('current');
    }
});

<div id="topNavigation">
<ul class="topLevelNavigation">
  <a href=".topLevelNavigation1" class="button"><li>Link #1</li></a>
  <a href=".topLevelNavigation2" class="button"><li>Link #2</li></a>
  <a href=".topLevelNavigation3" class="button"><li>Link #3</li></a>
  <a href=".topLevelNavigation4" class="button"><li>Link #4</li></a>
  <a href=".topLevelNavigation5" class="button"><li>Link #5</li></a>
  <a href="#box1" class="button"><li>Link #6</li></a>
  <a href="#box1" class="button"><li>Link #7</li></a>
  <a href="#box1" class="button"><li>Link #8</li></a>
  <a href="#box1" class="button"><li>Link #9</li></a>
  <a href="#box1" class="button"><li>Link #10</li></a>
  </ul>
  <ul class="topLevelNavigation2">
  <li>Link #1</li>
  <li>Link #2</li>
  <li>Link #3</li>
  <li>Link #4</li>
  <li>Link #5</li>
  <li>Link #6</li>
  <li>Link #7</li>
  <li>Link #8</li>
  <li>Link #9</li>
  <li>Link #10</li>
  </ul></div>
```

CSS

```
#topNavigation  {
margin-top:50px;
top: 0;
overflow:hidden;
postition:absolute;
}
ul.topLevelNavigation {
margin-left: 18px;
list-style: none;
}
ul.topLevelNavigation2, ul.topLevelNavigation3, ul.topLevelNavigation4,  {
margin-left: -55px;
}
ul.topLevelNavigation li {
color: #ccc;
font-size:24px;
margin:5px 0 10px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

A you can see here, it's not working http://keithfrenchdesigns.com/RunwayMag/index.html

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so any help would be amazing!

Comment: You realize most of your javascript is targeting an element with the class `.footer`, yet you have no such element in your markup ?

Comment: intention is to put a footer in at some point.(it was in there at one time) This is stopping things from working correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's throwing errors in the console when you access an element that isn't there and then try to get the offset of that element.

Comment: hmmm...well i commented that all out, and i'm still not working...

Comment: `$('.button').click(function(e) {` is not inside a document ready handler, so it's not working.

Comment: OK, i see what i forgot. I can now see it working in the code, but nothing is happening with the divs